# CakePHP 2.0 Plugin URL

Tags: cakephp, plugins, beta, cakephp-2.0

Trying to get CakePHP work with subfolders for Controllers, Views, or Models is not really working and from what I've read I need to use "Plugins". Right now I have the following folder structure:

```
/app/Plugin/Manager/
    /Controller
        CandyController.php
    /Models
    /View
        /Candy
            viewCandy.ctp
    ManagerAppController.php
    ManagerAppModel.php
```

When I try and set my url to: http://localhost/Manager/Candy/viewCandy/123. I get the error message: "ManagerController does not exist". Why is CakePHP not picking up that it should look in the Manager plugin folder?

Comment: Interestingly here is the answer. Edit /app/config/routes.php and add the line: CakePlugin::load(array('Manager'));

Comment: Yeah, I also noticed that CakePHP 2.0 doesn't load plugins automatically and allows you selectively load them. You should put this as an answer to your own question and accept it - you may even get the "Self-Learner" badge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now that 2.0 has been released the docs are fleshed out a bit more. This is described in the [Plugin section of the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#installing-a-plugin).

They suggest putting this in *bootstrap.php* instead of *routes.php*:

```
CakePlugin::loadAll(); // Loads all plugins at once
CakePlugin::load('ContactManager'); //Loads a single plugin
```

Comment: Switched answer. Thanks for keeping up to date

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution:

Go to /app/Config/routes.php and add the line `CakePlugin::load(array('YourPluginName'));` after the line `CakePlugin::routes();`. In my case it was line 40.

Basically CakePHP 2.0 doesn't automatically load plugins. I think that's fine and dandy, but there isn't really any documentation for this.

Comment: Plugins should be loaded on Config/bootstrap.php file, not Config/routes.php.